# How can I coordinate between COM port sends and receives?

Tags: c#, serial-port, compact-framework, port, windows-ce

I'm trying to refactor some ultra-complex legacy code that sends data from a handheld device to an app running on a PC, to which the handheld device is connected.

There is a "conversation" that goes on between the two apps that follows a protocol; the server (the app running on the PC) responds based on what the client tells it, and vice versa. Actually, the "conversation" can be seen about two thirds of the way down [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/819121/How-to-Capture-and-View-Local-Network-Traffic).

Anyway, my problem is: how can I let the client wait for the server to respond without interrupting it, or thinking it's not going to respond and failing to continue? This is what I have right now:

```
public class FileXferLegacy : IFileXfer
{
    private SerialPort cereal;
    private String lastDataReceived;
    private String receivedData;

    . . .

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method will be called when there is data waiting in the port's buffer
        try
        {
            receivedData += cereal.ReadLine();
            lastDataReceived = receivedData;
            ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("Received {0} in FileXferLegacy.SendDataContentsAsXML", receivedData));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #region IFileFetchSend Members

    . . .

    public void SendDataContentsAsXML(string destinationPath, string data)
    {
        byte[] stuff;
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached 
FileXferLegacy.SendDataContentsAsXML");
        cereal.Open();
        stuff = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PING" + "\n");
        cereal.Write(stuff, 0, stuff.Length);
        if (lastDataReceived.Contains("PING")) // Expecting "PING|ACKNOWLEDGE|"
        {
            stuff = 
System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LOGIN|foo|000003|LOC_HOST|PPP_PEER|1.4.0.42|bar" + "\n"); 
// TODO: replace this test data with dynamic data
            cereal.Write(stuff, 0, stuff.Length);
        }
        if (lastDataReceived.Contains("JOIN|LEVEL")) // Expecting something like "JOIN|LEVEL|1 
SETTING|ALT_ID|FALSE"
        {
            stuff = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HHTCOMMAND|GETHHTSUPDATE|"); 
            cereal.Write(stuff, 0, stuff.Length);
        }
        . . .
        String lastResponse = lastDataReceived; // Expecting something like 
"RESULT|FILECOMPLETE|INV_000003_whatever(not identical to what was sent earlier!).XML"
        // Parse out and do something with the filename ("INV_000003_whatever(not identical to 
what was sent earlier!).XML" above)
    }
```

As you can see, the client/handheld sends a string; it then reads "lastDataReceived" which is assigned in the DataReceived method. But what if there has been a delay, and "lastDataReceived" is null? What do I need to do to force a delay (without going to an extreme that would cause the app to appear slothlike in its slowness)? Or what is the way this should be done, if I'm totally off base?

Comment: is this the same question from earlier or is this a different issue...?

Comment: Handling delay tends to be more of a customer requirement than something that we can answer objectively. What do *you* want it to do if there is a delayed response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach is to use a reader thread that pulls bytes off the port with blocking reads (though   it can be done with async notification instead) and, once detecting that an entire message has been delivered, it either:

1. Puts them into a blocking queue (with consumer blocking on calls to dequeue until either a msg is added or a timeout reached

or

2. Notifies a listener with an event that contains the message.

Which of those two depends a lot on the consumer of those messages.  Your code above would benefit from #1, though if the consumer is the UI thread then you should look at #2.

Answer (score 2):

The protocol seems to be half-duplex so rewriting it with synchronous calls to Write/Readline seems to be the simplest way to handle it.